# mongodb replication not happening running on EC2

Tags: mongodb

I setup master/slave replication of mongodb on EC2. But I see not replication happening. When I do "show dbs" on master, it shows all dbs expected.

But when I do the same on replica, it does not show me any db.

Please help me troubleshoot.

On ubuntu 12.04 ec2 instance

```
 dpkg -l | grep mongo
ii  mongodb-10gen                    2.4.5                        An object/document-oriented database

rs.config()
{
    "_id" : "ittw",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "ip-10-304-48-93:27017"
        }
    ]
}

rs.config()
{
    "_id" : "ittw",
    "version" : 2,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "domU-17-31-19-16-88-5F:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "ec2-50-321-52-908.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017"
        }
    ]
}
rs.status() // replica
{
    "set" : "ittw",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-08-12T06:55:57Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "$ip:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 356039,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1375934685, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-08-08T04:04:45Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}



rs.status()  //Master
{
    "set" : "ittw",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-08-12T06:57:19Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "PRI_IP:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 356543,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1376289725, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-08-12T06:42:05Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "REP_IP:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 355869,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1375934685, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-08-08T04:04:45Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-08-12T06:57:17Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I see following lines in REPLIC logs:

```
Mon Aug 12 07:29:53.889 [initandlisten] connection accepted from $PRIMARY_IP:51376 #11921 (1 connection now open)
Mon Aug 12 07:30:23.922 [conn11921] end connection $PRIMARY_IP:51376 (0 connections now open)
Mon Aug 12 07:30:23.925 [initandlisten] connection accepted from $PRIMARY_IP:51377 #11922 (1 connection now open) 
Mon Aug 12 07:30:53.958 [conn11922] end connection $PRIMARY_IP:51377 (0 connections now open)
```

EDIT: After doing rs.initiate() and rs.add() on

```
rs.status()
{
    "set" : "ittw",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-08-12T18:25:20Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "PRIMARY_IP:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 1225,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1376331887, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-08-12T18:24:47Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "SECONDARY_IP:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 33,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1376331887, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-08-12T18:24:47Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-08-12T18:25:20Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2013-08-12T18:25:20Z"),
            "pingMs" : 10,
            "syncingTo" : "ip-10-190-185-227:27017"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I am going to assume you blanked out the ips. You have two primaries some how. There was a bug about this, what MongoDB version is this?

Comment: That is the shell version, hmm I will assume the MongoDB version is 2.4.5 but would be good to double check that. It is weird that the replica can't seem to communicate to the original primary....hmm

Comment: To me it simply looks like you did not issue ``rs.initiate()`` at all. Can you add to your question how ``rs.config()`` looks like on both machines?

Comment: A wild guess: if you downgraded to 2.2 and try again does it work?

Comment: Wait you did `initiate` on both machines? Hmm you shouldn't need to, you should ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/ ) do initiate on  primary and then add secondaries to that primaries config

Comment: That looks right now, what about rs on the secondary? Is your data on the secondary?

Comment: SO/Rocks...you guys rock.....it works now...simple mistake but found help on SO struggling alone.....THANKS A LOT!!!..cleaned up some of my comments.

Comment: NP, this could be a bug actually where if you combine two inited sets and add one set as a secondary of the other you get this, if you have a chance I would open a jira with this info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems it is not electing a unique primary, try if this helps in electing a unique primary.

when you initiate your two replica set members make sure they all have the same value for the replSet parameter, issue

```
 rs.initiate()
 rs.conf()
```

on your proposed primary. Then try to add your secondary with forced priority:

```
rs.add( { "_id": 1, "host": "mongodbd3.example.net:27017", "priority": 0 } )
```

Hence it will only be able to elect as secondary.

Comment: I think the main point is that on the primary it shouldn't be able to elect both as primary anyway, physically, it is the fact that the secondary cannot see the primary after the primary was inited and the secondary added to the set